# Is the WikiBook "Stack Exchange Guide" legitimate?

Tags: discussion, help

After realizing I could learn more about Stack Exchange, I started googling "Stack Exchange Guide", so I could learn more about the different Stack Exchange sites and start branching out my questions from Stack Overflow.

In the process, I found this WikiBook: *[The Stack Exchange User Guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/The_Stack_Exchange_User_Guide)*

The author is "benonsoftware", but I am not sure if there's a connection.

I wanted to see if it's legitimate and/or there will be more to come in the future? I think this is a cool idea whether Stack Exchange created or user-created.

Comment: What do you mean by "legitimate"?

Comment: By legit, is it either a StackExchange-backed project or is it a WikiBook with solid users behind it who intend to finish and maintain it. My bad if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: If you're looking for other sources of information, the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/) and [Community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) have tons of information...

Comment: @KevinVermeer very helpful indeed, although I realized that more and more sites like "Super User" and "IT Security" are popping up, but there's not much material to help a n00b learn about them or if their question is better suited with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an official project, but  was started by [George Edison,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65234/the-need-to-introduce-beginners-to-the-stack-exchange-platform) who definitely is a solid Meta/SO user. However, I don't think the project gained enough momentum - it's a year old with no visible activity.

Comment: Ah thanks for sharing that link. I'll look through the history of that question, I might learn a little in the process by contributing to it. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for crediting me! Yeah, I started that a loooong time back as a beginner's guide. I'm glad it's starting to turn up in search results now.