# Can we get a "welcome, check out our FAQ" notification for new users?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, new-users

I've just created my first (?) [sock puppet account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/61598/smelly-sock) on Programmers. This is the first notification I was greeted with:

[image: Smelly Sock's first day!]

I think the first ever notification should point the new user to the FAQ, or, if setting your name and email is *so important*, perhaps there could be a second notification. Something along the lines of:

> Hey! Check out our FAQ to see what questions we welcome!

The [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) especially is awesome, kinda reads like a short novel, and I think we should help new users discover it as soon as possible. Thoughts?

---

An alternative would be to use the nice transparent, white bar that we get when we are automatically logged in, as [Bryan Dunsmore suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143058/can-we-get-a-welcome-check-out-our-faq-notification-for-new-users#comment406330_143058).

Comment: IIRC, it was that way back in the days of the gold top bar

Comment: @Kevin It would be nice if we could get that, but using the nice transparent, white bar that we get when we are automatically logged in.

Comment: New users (rep < *n*) should get training wheel pages (aka a "Wizard") to help them to formulate good questions.

Comment: I would prefer a pop-up to a notification. New users (including me) need to know certain important thumb rules on how this site works.

Comment: @skinnyTOD: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/create-a-guided-tour-for-new-users