# Focus on reputation earning on the SE tour for new users

Tags: discussion, tour

Recently there has been created a new About page, and a short Tour for new users on Stack Exchange, which is really the solution for [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188112/135505).

I think this is great, but there was one thing I was a bit surprised about regarding the focus on how to gain reputation:

> Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your questions, answers and edits.
>
> [image: Reputation score]

Here is mentioned that you get +2  for edit approved. For new users, I think instead, it would be more important to emphasize that you get points for accepting an answer to your question.

Comment: I'm not really sure that should be part of the "This is how you get rep" explanation. It is already stated before that you can mark an answer as accepted and that it means that the answered worked for the person accepting it. That seems enough to me. I'm not sure I like the idea of linking it as accepting == rep.

Comment: Improving content is far more important than accepting answers.

Comment: @AsheeshR: Generally maybe, but not necessarily as an important responsibility for new users.

Comment: I disagree. Editing is an important thing to know about for all users, *especially new users*. If anything, rep should be de-emphasized from the entire about page IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the point of this box is to illustrate the most important features of Stack Exchange. There are entries for:

- asking questions;
- answering questions;
- accepting answers;
- editing.

That's good: each item illustrates one feature. Adding the reputation obtained from accepting answers would make the list longer by one more item without showing more about Stack Exchange.

If you're proposing this because you want to encourage askers to accept answers, this wouldn't be effective. New users who participate solely to ask questions don't care about reputation anyway, they care about getting answers. Teaching them that accepting answers is a core feature is good, but telling them that they can reputation equivalent to 0.4 upvote for it isn't going to make a difference. And don't forget that not everyone starts by asking questions; this overview is for everyone, not just for dedicated askers.

Removing the entry about editing would be bad. Editing is a core feature of Stack Exchange, it's good to show that it exists and you can be rewarded for it.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that you can actually do a suggested edit without even being logged in, but you can't vote.