# Page for creating new chat rooms still links to the old /faq page

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks

The page for [creating a new chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) includes the following message.

> Rooms are each associated with a specific site in the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and are expected to be on the same topic as that site - for example a room for the [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) site should be about cooking, as described in the **[cooking faq](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq)**.

**The description should be updated, as the old `/faq` page no longer exists, and redirects users to the [tour page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour).**

> Rooms are each associated with a specific site in the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and are expected to be on the same topic as that site - for example a room for the [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) site should be about cooking, as described in the **[cooking tour page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour)**.

This also applies when creating chat rooms on sites with their own separate chat servers ([Stack Overflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/new)):

> Rooms are expected to be on the same topics as Stack Overflow, as described in the [Stack Overflow faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

and:

> Rooms are expected to be on the same topics as Meta Stack Exchange, as described in the [Meta Stack Exchange faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: On a related note, the hyperlink for "[cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) site" should probably be extended to "[cooking site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)"

Answer (score 1):

I think `/faq` had been used in olden days before the help-center. So, all faq links will redirect to help center now<sup>[1]</sup>. After introducing tour page<sup>[2]</sup>, now  just `/faq` and `/about` will redirect you to `/tour` page on any site of SE network.

[1] [Introducing a brand new, consolidated, Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/260388)

[2] [Create a guided tour for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126009/260388)

Comment: True, before the Help Center there was a /faq where 10k users could edits the sections on Meta and it would propagate to the rest of the sites on daily basis. It worked pretty well, but Help Center is even better. The text "cooking faq" should simply be changed to "cooking Help Center" and link to its help center.